# Setting EC2 Environment Variables with CodeDeploy, Parameter Store and PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2, aws-code-deploy, aws-ssm

I am deploying a Node.js app to EC2 using CodeDeploy. I am storing credentials within AWS Systems Manager, Parameter Store however cannot find a method to expose these to my application.

I am using PM2 for process management. I can successfully retrieve the parameter from the Parameter Store on the target machine, so there are no permission issues. For example:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --region us-east-1 --names LOCAL_CACHE_PATH --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value`
```

...successfully returns the correct string. I attempt to use this in my `applicationStart.sh` CodeDeploy file and start the app:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LOCAL_CACHE_PATH=$(aws ssm get-parameters --region us-east-1 --names LOCAL_CACHE_PATH --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value)

pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

`LOCAL_CACHE_PATH` returns `undefined` in my app when accessing `process.env.LOCAL_CACHE_PATH`.

So the environment variable is available within the `applicationStart.sh` script and yet undefined when the app starts from that script.

I am looking for a recommended approach to use environment variables from the Parameter Store with CodeDeploy.

I have read literally dozens of posts on similar topics but cannot resolve it. Very much appreciate any guidance.

Comment: make sure the IAM role/user assigned to the code deploy  has the necessary permission to retrieve parameters from SSM

Comment: As noted, the `ssm get-parameters` request successfully returns so there are no permission issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I am using is to write the environment variables to a .env file and use that in my app:

`afterInstall.sh`:

```
echo LOCAL_CACHE_PATH=$(aws ssm get-parameters --output text --region us-east-1 --names LOCAL_CACHE_PATH --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value) >> /home/ubuntu/foo/.env
```